# Teradata Least function giving unexpected result when used with negative input

Tags: teradatasql

I am trying convert an age in days into age buckets such that there are 365 days in each 12 buckets (11 x 30) + 35. To get around the uneven number of days in the age buckets I am using the FLOOR function to extract the full years and the CEILING & MOD functions to calculate the age bucket for the remaining part year. I am using the LEAST function to force days 361-365 into the 12th age bucket, but it gives very unexpected values if the AGE_OF_INCIDENT is negative.

These are the calculations I am using. AGE_OF_INCIDENT is my input and AGE_BUCKET is the output I am looking for; I have added the other three to show how the parts are calculating.
`,FLOOR(CAST(PREV.AGE_OF_INCIDENT AS DECIMAL(8,4))/365)*12 as fFLOOR ,CEILING((CAST(PREV.AGE_OF_INCIDENT AS DECIMAL(6,2))MOD 365)/30) AS fCEILING ,LEAST(CEILING((CAST(PREV.AGE_OF_INCIDENT AS DECIMAL(6,2))MOD 365)/30),12) AS fLEAST ,FLOOR(CAST(PREV.AGE_OF_INCIDENT AS DECIMAL(8,4))/365)*12 + LEAST(CEILING((CAST(PREV.AGE_OF_INCIDENT AS DECIMAL(6,2))MOD 365)/30),12) AS AGE_BUCKET`
This is a sample of my output:

AGE_OF_INCIDENT fFLOOR  fCEILING    fLEAST  AGE_BUCKET
-405    -12 -1  65535   65523
-370    -12 0   0   -12
-336    0   -11 65525   65525
-32 0   -1  65535   65535
2   0   1   1   1
360 0   12  12  12
364 0   13  12  12
365 12  0   0   12
729 12  13  12  24
730 24  0   0   24
731 24  1   1   25
[image]

Why is this happening and is there some tweak I can make to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have non-standard UDFs named CEILING, FLOOR, and/or LEAST in the SYSLIB database which gets searched prior to Teradata-supplied TD_SYSFNLIB. Try qualifying those function names, e.g. TD_SYSFNLIB.FLOOR.

Comment: Thanks Fred. That is exactly what it was - the LEAST function needs that qualifier. I would never have known to try that.